# Store distinct li item by class in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I would like to insert some distinct list elements in a text area. I have something like this

```
<ul id="each-1">
    <li class="remove"><img src="img/del.png"></li>
    <li class="name">sushi</li>
    <li class="price">45</li>
    <li class="substract"><img src="img/minus.png"></li>
    <li class="add"><img src="img/plus.png"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="each-2">
    <li class="remove"><img src="img/del.png"></li>
    <li class="name">pizza</li>
    <li class="price">10</li>
    <li class="substract"><img src="img/minus.png"></li>
    <li class="add"><img src="img/plus.png"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to store the "name" and "price" classes elements of each ul list into a text area using javascript. I will have something like:

sushi 45

pizza 10

Thanks for help

Comment: Please show your attempts or research efforts to solve this. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code** that isn't working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var text = "";                                    // the text that will be inserted into the textarea (initialize with "")
$("li.name").each(function() {                    // for each li.name element
  text += $(this).text() + " ";                   // add the text of that element (name) to text, followed by a space
  text += $(this).next("li.price").text() + "\n"; // add the text of its next li.price element (price), followed by a new line
});

$("#ta").val(text);                               // set the value of the text area to the accumulated string
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
<ul id="each-1">
    <li class="remove"><img src="img/del.png"></li>
    <li class="name">sushi</li>
    <li class="price">45</li>
    <li class="substract"><img src="img/minus.png"></li>
    <li class="add"><img src="img/plus.png"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="each-2">
    <li class="remove"><img src="img/del.png"></li>
    <li class="name">pizza</li>
    <li class="price">10</li>
    <li class="substract"><img src="img/minus.png"></li>
    <li class="add"><img src="img/plus.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

I loops through all your `ul` and extract the data you want, and add them to the `str`. When its done it adds the `str` to the `textarea`

```js
var str = "";
$("ul[id^='each']").each(function() {
  var name = $(this).find(".name").text();
  var price = $(this).find(".price").text();

  str += name + " " + price + "\n";
})
  
$("textarea").val(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="each-1">
  <li class="name">sushi</li>
  <li class="price">45</li>
</ul>
<ul id="each-2">
  <li class="name">pizza</li>
  <li class="price">10</li>
</ul>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very helpful !